# Fields data types are changed to "Char" in R dataframe created from mongoDB and weird value in the "recDate" field

Tags: r, mongodb

When i try to insert data from mongoDB to R different data types of fields are converted into "Char" vlaues in R dataframe.

This is how the data is in MongoDB--
Field data types on MongoDb--

```
AggregatedIS DOUBLE,
 AggregatedLISR DOUBLE,
 AggregatedAvgPos  DOUBLE,
 SearchLostISBudget DOUBLE,
 QualityScore DOUBLE
 recdate TIMESTAMP and etc..
```

This is the query that i used to load the data frame in R from mongoDB--

```
> DBNS = "somaweb.aggregatedadwords"
> aggregated = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FLASE)
> cursor = mongo.find(mongo,DBNS)
> i=1
> while(mongo.cursor.next(cursor)){
+ tmp = mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))
+ tmp.df = as.data.frame(t(unlist(tmp)),stringsAsFactors = F)
+ aggregated = rbind.fill(aggregated,tmp.df)
+ }
```

---

On seeing the above code,

data types for "tmp" data frame are--
str(tmp)

```
 $ _id               :Class 'mongo.oid'  atomic [1:1] 3149168
  .. ..- attr(*, "mongo.oid")=<externalptr> 
 $ DayName           : chr "Saturday"
 $ AggregatedIS      : num 0.235
 $ AggregatedLISR    : num 0.765
 $ AggregatedAvgPos  : num 3.59
 $ SearchLostISBudget: num -2.22e-16
 $ QualityScore      : num 0
 $ accountID         : int 88
 **$ recdate           : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-07-03 20:00:00"**
 $ campaign          : chr "Belt Buckles"
 $ impressions       : int 1435
 $ clicks            : int 23
 $ cost              : num 4.59
 $ revenue           : num 0
 $ conversions       : int 0
```

then data types for tmp.df are-

str(tmp.df)

```
'data.frame':   706 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ _id               : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ DayName           : chr  "Wednesday" "Wednesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" 
 $ AggregatedIS      : chr  "0.872131180124224" "0.902400244498777" 
 $ AggregatedLISR    : chr  "0.127868819875776" "0.0296464547677262" 
 $ AggregatedAvgPos  : chr  "2.25850931677019" "1.54327628361858" 
 $ SearchLostISBudget: chr  "1.11022302462516e-16" "0.0679533007334964"
 $ QualityScore      : chr  "6.77018633540373" "7.37652811735941"
 $ accountID         : chr  "88" "88" "88" "88" ...
 **$ recdate           : chr  "1388534400" "1388534400" "1388534400"** 
 $ campaign          : chr  "Belts" "Custom" "Belt Buckles" "Belt Buckles" 
 $ impressions       : chr  "805" "409" "4491" "4501" ...
 $ clicks            : chr  "49" "48" "153" "167" ...
 $ cost              : chr  "23.04" "24.71" "52.37" "55.31" ...
 $ revenue           : chr  "100.01" "0" "178.57" "248.85" ...
 $ conversions       : chr  "1" "0" "3" "2" ...
```

Comparing the data types of variables to "mongoDB", "tmp" and "tmp.df",

1.we can see from the above outputs all the data types are converted to "character" --- able to convert using as.numeric(as.character(field_name))

2. but if we see the "recdate" field in "tmp" dataframe, it extracted in good way as it is in "mongoDB" but when i unlist and create a dataframe as "tmp.df" it gives weird values which are not even dates!! Unable to convert "date" similarly that i did with other fields.

Could someone please help if you faced similar situations? And i am even trying to understand what exactly query is working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will return the data types as required--

```
> #conversion of datatypes of different fields
> agg<-within(agg,{AggregatedIS<-as.numeric(as.character(AggregatedIS))
+ AggregatedLISR<-as.numeric(as.character(AggregatedLISR))
+ AggregatedAvgPos<-as.numeric(as.character(AggregatedAvgPos))
+ SearchLostISBudget<-as.numeric(as.character(SearchLostISBudget))
+ QualityScore<-as.numeric(as.character(QualityScore))
+ recdate<-as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(recdate)),origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT")
+ #campaign<-as.character(campaign))-- dont consider as it is char
+ clicks<-as.integer(as.character(clicks))
+ impressions<-as.integer(as.character(impressions))
+ cost<-as.numeric(as.character(cost))
+ revenue<-as.numeric(as.character(revenue))
+ conversions<-as.integer(as.character(conversions))
+ })
```

Recdate values are UNIX TIMESTAMP values converted to date format!